# Object of class Magento\Store\Model\Group\Interceptor could not be converted to int

Tags: magento2, multistore, group

I'm getting this error :

> Notice: Object of class Magento\Store\Model\Group\Interceptor could not be converted to int in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3065

The responsible piece of code is somewhere in it

```
foreach ($stores as $store){
    $storeId = $store->getId();
    $storeCode = $store->getCode();
    if($this->isProStore($storeCode)){
        $storeGroupId = $store->getStoreGroupId();
        $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
        if($storeGroupId !== null){
            $group->load($storeGroupId);
            $group->setRootCategoryId($rootCategoryId);
            $group->save();
            $factoryStore = $this->storeFactory->create();
            $factoryStore->load($storeId);
            $factoryStore->setStoreGroupId($group);
            $factoryStore->save();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually It was just a dumb mistakes I was setting `$group` instead of `$group->getId()`